# Using x-apple-reminder:// to launch the Reminders app in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa, reminders

Seems simple but I can't make this work.. I want to launch the native Reminders app from my native app.

From what I've read I need to use `x-apple-reminder://` URL scheme but it does not launch the Reminders app.

Here's my code:

```
NSString* reminderUrl = @"x-apple-reminder://";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:reminderUrl];
BOOL ok = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

`ok` is always `NO` and nothing happens.

I also tried passing in the Reminder's id (my app created it), but that didn't work. (as in `x-apple-reminder://REMINDER_GUID`)

I suspect that my problem is with the `openURL` call.. is there some other option?

Comment: Where do you got the url scheme for reminder app??

Comment: StackOverflow, and here: http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/reminders

Comment: But it is not referenced anywhere in the documentation by apple. I don't know for sure, it will work or not. If you are trying using simulator, check it in the device.

Comment: Btw if anyone finds this useful, IT DOES WORK on a device, just not on the emulator. (Reminders app not on the emulator it seems)

Comment: New (iOS 13) Url is : x-apple-reminderkit://

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the way, apparently, Apple is against using undocumented URL schemes, take a look:

http://www.iphonehacks.com/2013/10/launch-center-pro-undocumented-urls-apple-apps.html

Available schemes are documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: While your answer is very useful, it's not really an answer, more a comment.